# Where can I find documentation for Excel's Pictures collection?

Tags: vba, excel

I have seen [many references](http://www.google.com/search?q=excel+Pictures.Insert) to doing something like the following to insert a picture in Excel:

```
Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PathToPicture)
```

Where can I find the canonical documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find this in the doco in VBA for Excel 2007... i have seen a few things go missing in the VBA doco between 2003 and 2007.

So my first suggestion is look in a copy of Excel or Access 2003 help files.

In the past i've used the Shapes collection for images and shapes, which is handy for iterating over them later on. Eg;

```
sh.Shapes.AddPicture "c:\temp\pic.jpg", True, True, 0, 0, 80, 60
```

However you will need to know the size of the image, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I can't find any official documentation either, despite hunting everywhere. Can we safely assume this is an undocumented feature (and thus should be used with caution)?

Comment: Yep i'd agree. It doesn't seem to be a member of WorkSheet (i just checked the Excel 2003 VBA doco). Maybe it appears if you do a macro record which is why it's everywhere.

Comment: The image will be rendered in its original size if you use -1 as widht and height: sh.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\temp\pic.jpg", True, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)