# Alternative to the Pictures collection in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-2010, vba

Here is some code from an **xls** file. In Excel 2010 it doesn't work. I can't find the collection `Pictures` in the object explorer

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

        Dim oPic As Picture
        'make them invisible
        For Each oPic In Me.Pictures
                    If Left(oPic.Name, 2) = "jq" Then
                                oPic.Visible = False
                    End If
        Next

end sub
```

What would the equivalent 2010 code be?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138914/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-excels-pictures-collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to loop through pictures in Excel

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
            Debug.Print shp.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Siddharth ... am I right in saying that this is new to the latest version of xl?

Comment: ok - so the pictures collection has been dropped but the shapes has always been ok?