# Check if exists an image in a range of cells in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file in which I want check if exists an image in a range of cells.

I've been trying with the following code:

```
Sub findImage(Cell As Range)
   Dim Caddress As String
   Dim Pict As Excel.Picture
   Application.Volatile
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Caddress = Cell.Address 'Assign the range
   For Each Pict In ActiveSheet.Pictures 'Check for each picture in the range
      If Pict.TopLeftCell.Address = Caddress Then 'if exists in the range shows a message
        MsgBox "The image exists!"
         Exit For 'break for
         Exit Sub 'break sub
      End If
   Next Pict
   MsgBox "NO", vbInformation 'if not exists shows a message
End Sub
```

This code doesn't works, this shows an error "not compatible types Err. 13".

Any question post on comments.

Comment: How are you calling this? Where does the error occur? I was able to get it to run via Immediate Window, using `Call findImage(Range("C13"))`.  Also note, even if an image is found, you'll get the "NO" message box. Take out the `Exit For`, and just leave `Exit Sub`.

Comment: I'm calling this Sub with a button `Dim asd As Range` 
`Set asd = Range("F10")`  `Call findImage(asd)`

Comment: The error occurs in the for each statement

Comment: Seems like maybe there's a non-picture in the `Pictures` collection for some reason. Try running `For Each obj In ActiveSheet.Pictures: MsgBox TypeName(obj): Next` in another Sub real quick, and tell us what the popups say (most importantly, does any of them say something other than "Picture")

Comment: In any case, it's good practice in modern Excel to use `Shapes` instead of `Pictures`, which seems to be deprecated. Loop through `Shapes` and check `Shape.Type = msoPicture` (described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12280723/3397613)

Comment: @Mikegrann Another important thing that I forgot to say, i have two pictures in the top of the sheet, but I don't think it matters. The result of your code was Picture, Picture, OLEObject, Picture, then i suppose the picture its recognized in the activesheet

Comment: @TimeToCode yep, an OLEObject snuck into the `Pictures` collection. So when you tried to assign it to the loop variable, an `Excel.Picture`, you got a type mismatch. Time to switch to the manual checking I described...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked the code a little (removed the `.Select` line) and added `haveImage` boolean value, to make the code a little more logical. I also changed `Cell` to `Cel`, as I've found using `Cell` can get confused with `Cells`.

```
Sub findImage(Cel As Range)
Dim Caddress As String
Dim shp    As Shape
Dim haveImage As Boolean

haveImage = False

Application.Volatile
' Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Caddress = Cel.Address      'Assign the range
For Each shp In Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes    'Check for each picture in the range
    If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = Caddress Then    'if exists in the range shows a message
            haveImage = True
            Exit Sub             'break sub
        End If
    End If
Next shp

If haveImage Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "NO", vbInformation    'if not exists shows a message
End If
End Sub
```

To use this, you would call it like this: `Call findimage(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12"))`

Note: If the cell has a picture that does *not* have the top-left corner of that picture, in the cell, it's going to return "No".

Comment: The error keeps coming at Line `Next Pict`, i don´t not why!

Comment: @TimeToCode - It runs through it once, then errors? Or doesn't even run once, and highlights that line?  Although it sounds like Mikegrann has good recommendations.

Comment: @BruceWayne It probably stops after a few runs when it encounters the OLEObject and tries to assign between incompatible types. See comments on the original Question. EDIT: And with the sneaky edit, it appears you've already read them. Whoops.

Comment: @TimeToCode - Try it now, I edited with Mike's comments.

Comment: @Mikegrann - I think I took your comments into account, great thinking. I realized too that I may be "stealing" an answer from you, which is not my intention! I can revert the code back, and you can add an answer for OP if you like.

Comment: @BruceWayne No worries, the code part was mostly Siddharth's doing anyway! If OP has code that works, that's what matters most.

Comment: The code now works fine, the button was the problem, thx a lot @Mikegrann

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Application.Intersect() while Cell.Adress returns "A1" and Shape adress "$A$1".

rng As Range

```
For Each shp In Sheets("SheetName").Shapes
    Dim ints As Range
    Set ints = Application.Intersect(Sheets("SheetName").Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address), rngF)
    If (Not (ints Is Nothing)) Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
Next shp
```