# Select a picture in the active cell

Tags: vba, excel

How do I select a picture inside an active cell? I am trying to make a macro that inserts a picture and resizes it to the size of the cell. With some help, I have made the following code to insert the picture:

```
ActiveCell.Select
Dim picname As String
picname = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert "C:\Users\Briet\Documents\PAJ\pic-presentation\Images\" & picname & ".jpg"
```

Once the picture is inserted, its container cell is selected, but not the actual picture. So the following code, which resizes the picture to the cell, does not work:

```
On Error GoTo NOT_SHAPE
Dim PicWtoHRatio As Single
Dim CellWtoHRatio As Single
With Selection
PicWtoHRatio = .Width / .Height
End With
With Selection.TopLeftCell
CellWtoHRatio = .Width / .RowHeight
End With
Select Case PicWtoHRatio / CellWtoHRatio
Case Is > 1
With Selection
.Width = .TopLeftCell.Width
.Height = .Width / PicWtoHRatio
End With
Case Else
With Selection
.Height = .TopLeftCell.RowHeight
.Width = .Height * PicWtoHRatio
End With
End Select
With Selection
.Top = .TopLeftCell.Top
.Left = .TopLeftCell.Left
End With
Exit Sub
NOT_SHAPE:
MsgBox "Select a picture before running this macro."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Insert()` returns a reference to the inserted picture, so you can work directly with that.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim shp, rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C3")

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\_Stuff\pic.jpg")
    With shp
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = .Width / Application.Max(.Width / rng.Width, _
                                          .Height / rng.Height)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I declared shp and set it equal to the inserted picture just like you said, then just used shp.Select, and everything worked. Thank you!

Comment: I tried your code and I get a runtime error on the first line after With shp

Comment: Sorry - I was making a few edits.  You've accepted the answer, so I assume it's working now?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to adjust the picture if you have the cell selected.  You need to select the picture itself.  According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138914/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-excels-pictures-collection) on SO, the Pictures collection is undocumented.  When I googled it, I couldn't find it either.  I believe that once you have the cell selected you can get the picture object from [the ShapeRange collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174304%28v=office.11%29.aspx).  It has a required argument of *index*, but if you only have one shape, that value should be 1.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction.