# How can I insert an image to cell on vba?

Tags: vba, image

I'm working on this excel macro and the code I've been writing on (as bad as I can expect) checks every cell on the G:G range, and according to  its value, it inserts an image. Truth is I don't know exactly how to make that the image gets inserted in the cell that has been checked. 
I attach the code as I wrote it...

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim Cell As Range
   For Each Cell In Range("G:G")

   If Cell.Value = 1 Then
   Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("S:\10_INGENIERÍA DE FUNDICIÓN\03_CALIDAD\Calidad central\Septiembre 2019\IMAGENES\C1.png", _
   msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 25, 25)

   ElseIf Cell.Value = 2 Then
   Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("S:\10_INGENIERÍA DE FUNDICIÓN\03_CALIDAD\Calidad central\Septiembre 2019\IMAGENES\C2.png", _
   msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 25, 25)


   ElseIf Cell.Value = 3 Then
   Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("S:\10_INGENIERÍA DE FUNDICIÓN\03_CALIDAD\Calidad central\Septiembre 2019\IMAGENES\C3.png", _
   msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 25, 25)


   ElseIf Cell.Value = 4 Then
   Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("S:\10_INGENIERÍA DE FUNDICIÓN\03_CALIDAD\Calidad central\Septiembre 2019\IMAGENES\C4.png", _
   msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 25, 25)


   End If

   Next

   End Sub
```

As I click on the command button, the images get inserted next to A1, and they're one over another. I want them to be in the cell where the checked value was, on range G:G. 
I've been reading about it, and I've been trying many different ways but since I'm not good at vba (or any other language) I'm totally lost and a little desesperate.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103919/select-a-picture-in-the-active-cell/21104067#21104067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the Left and Top properties as follows...

```
Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("S:\10_INGENIERÍA DE FUNDICIÓN\03_CALIDAD\Calidad central\Septiembre 2019\IMAGENES\C1.png", _
   msoCTrue, msoCTrue, Cell.Left, Cell.Top, 25, 25)
```

However, your macro can be re-written as follows...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim PathToFolder As String
    PathToFolder = "S:\10_INGENIERÍA DE FUNDICIÓN\03_CALIDAD\Calidad central\Septiembre 2019\IMAGENES\"

    'Make sure path ends in backslash (\)
    If Right(PathToFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        PathToFolder = PathToFolder & "\"
    End If

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ImageFile As String
    For Each Cell In Range("G1:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row) 'define range until last used row
        If Len(Cell) > 0 Then 'cell contains a value
            If Cell.Value = 1 Then
                ImageFile = PathToFolder & "C1.png"
            ElseIf Cell.Value = 2 Then
                ImageFile = PathToFolder & "C2.png"
            ElseIf Cell.Value = 3 Then
                ImageFile = PathToFolder & "C3.png"
            ElseIf Cell.Value = 4 Then
                ImageFile = PathToFolder & "C4.png"
            Else
                ImageFile = ""
            End If
            If Len(ImageFile) > 0 Then 'variable contains a non-empty string
                If Len(Dir(ImageFile, vbNormal)) > 0 Then 'image file exists
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture ImageFile, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, Cell.Left, Cell.Top, 25, 25
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```